# Are Neo4J node ids optimized for access?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, nodes

I am building a large graph database using neo4j.

I have my own external indexes which give me identifiers for relevant nodes that I use for further neo4j graph traversal. In other words I already have my start node ids when I get to query the database.

My question is: can node lookups be faster if I use neo4j/lucene indexes to access relevant nodes?

Or are queries such as:

```
START n=node({ids})
```

already optimized for node access and nothing can be gained by using:

```
START n=node:nodeIndexName(key={value})
```

?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Neo4j is optimized for Node ID as at the persistence level, all nodes are a block, so accessing node 100 is like accessing block 100.

I will warn you though that Neo4j makes no guarantee about the node id if you delete it. Neo4j reclaims ID's. So if in the course of your DB's life you delete and add multiple nodes, your external entries may be "valid" but not what you'd expect.

//EDIT: Also, why not just use Lucene to perform your lookups? Of course accessing the Node ID is faster, but that's what Lucene does under the cover when you do a lookup, so `key:name, value:frank` will return `node id 5123` and neo4j will return the node that corresponds to that ID.

Comment: Well put. Better to make your own identifiers if you're doing external lookups.

Comment: @WesFreeman Exactly, Just use a UUID as a property and index.

Comment: @Nicolas: Thanks, I actually use Lucene for lookups, but my lookups are based on complex fulltext queries with a special syntax and dedicated token streams, so I run them externally at the moment. The results of the lookups are node ids. So I'll stick with them for now with and see if this creates persistence issues of the kind you've mentioned...

Comment: The safer option would be to use a UUID as a property/lucene index in Neo4j, and store that UUId externally when you want to do your external lookup.